# php: casting a class to its descendant?

Tags: php, class, inheritance, casting

I'm developing a game and there exists a class `Player` that extends more basic class. Players can navigate, fire, get intel, build etc. Currently all these functions are defined in a single class and the source code and styling is becoming cumbersome as the functionality grows.
I would like to create some derived specialized classes such as `class Navigator extends Player`, `class Fighter extends Player` and so on, which will help me spread all functions by subject across several source modules to ease their maintenance.
At the same time, I want to be able to create only a single instance of `Player` class since the gameplay requires explicit use of its functions too. So I'd dream of something along the lines

```
    $p = new Player();
    $p->SomethingGeneric();
    ((Fighter) $p)->Fire();
    ((Navigator) $p)->MoveTo();
```

That is, I want to invoke the methods of derived classes without creating their separate instances explicitly, since specialized methods will also call `Player` methods and rely on its properties as well.
So I googled for some language magic, such as polymorphism, interfaces and type casting in php but the simplest and most elegant solution is yet to be found. By elegant I mean that whenever I want to add something that derived class can do, I only change its definition and make method calls in the main project. Either I'm not too observant or all examples of polymorphism I've found so far only show how the instances of derived classes can pretend to be each other, which is not the case here.
Thanks in advance.

upd1: It seems I was not clear enough on the gameplay design and what I mean to achieve.
Here, navigation, combat and building are not mutually exclusive functions pertaining to the player classes. There are no player classes. Users control players identical in terms of actions available to them. Depending on the situation and scenery, user may choose to navigate, fight, build or whatever. More importantly, user may choose to do some miscellany which is not specialized enough to be separated by an action group, such as to resolve other player ids into their names, etc.
It seems natural therefore to have only one `Player` object per user (which I currently do) but single-class design forces me to implement player functionality in a way such as

```
    public function Navigation_MoveTo()
    public function Navigation_GetETA()
    public function Combat_FireWeapon()
    public function Combat_RechargeHP()
    public function Intel_GetLocalChat()
```

That is UGLY, because it forces me to either have all player code in a many thousands source lines in a single file or to do some include-perversions.
Hence the question: is there a way to add one more layer of elegant abstraction above that so that I can write classes for navigation, combat etc derived from `Player` in a separate source files while at the same time using only one instance of `Player` class per user, because I would need to call `Player` AND `Navigator` AND `Fighter` methods on it depending on what users chooses to do at any given moment.
I hope that clarifies it a little more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

I would suggest looking into [`traits`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php). Using traits will allow you to reuse code kept in smaller, more manageable components yet still inject their functionality into multiple classes (and have a single class have the capability to use multiple traits).  An example I can come up with sorta-modelled on your example:

```
trait FightingTrait {
    protected $weapon;

    public function fireWeapon()
    {
        $this->weapon->fire();
    }
}

trait NavigatingTrait {
    public function moveTo($location){ /* Implementation */ }

    public function eta(){ /* Implementation */ }
}

class Player
{
    use FightingTrait, NavigatingTrait;
}
```

If you happen to have *other* things that may need to fire or move, you could take advantage of these traits there, too:

```
class Vehicle {
    use FightingTrait, NavigatingTrait;
}
```

**Previous**

I don't think you want to do this. At first glance I believe this is a fundamental violation of the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Very generally:

> If S is a subtype of T, then objects of T may be replaced with objects of Type S.

It *does not* go both ways: you cannot replace `S` with `T`, because `S` can have added functionality that is not available on `T`.  You have a concrete `Player` object (`T`) and you are attempting to force that object to be of one of your subtypes (`S`), and this is not how inheritance is supposed to work. A *Fighter* **is a** *Player*, but a *Player* is not necessarily a *Fighter*. It could also be a *Navigator*, or any other potential subtype you may want in the future.

If you want to maintain this inheritance chain (`Fighter > Player`, `Navigator > Player`), then I would suggest instead designing it a bit differently. Make `Player` an `abstract` class, because you want to use it to group functionality that is *shared* across all of your different base types. Should all of your different player types have the ability to `MoveTo()` or `Fire()`? Then it belongs in the `Player` class.  If `Navigators` can do something different that `Fighters` cannot (and vice versa), then that logic belongs in the subtype and not in the shared parent.

Note that in this case `Player` is abstract and you would never actually instantiate an object of type `Player`. You only want to have a single instance, which is fine, but make that `Player` instance one of the concrete base classes (e.g. `Fighter` or `Navigator`) because those types *are* a `Player`.

Comment: Sorry, it seems I was not clear enough as to the gameplay design. Navigators and Fighters are not separate player classes, they are functions any player can do, i.e. players in this game do not differ in terms of available actions. I will provide more details in the edit of the original question.